# single test failing after changing to capybara-webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-chrome, selenium, rspec, capybara

I have written some RSpec test for my rails 3.2 application and because I was annyoed by the Browser popping up ich tried to change from firefox to `capybara-webkit`.
After this all tests still run, except one. The line that is failing is:

```
expect { click_button "Create" }.to change(Answer, :count).by(count)
```

If I remove the expect and add a method to take a screenshot before and after, I can see that the test is run correctly. But if I step trough with the Debugger the log shows me that the records get created after the second screenshot line. I can wait forever the click_button and corresponding Controller action is run after the line next line is executed.

The "create" button is a standard html button, no JS is involved in the create action. Does sb have a explaination for this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a race condition here between Capybara sending the click action to the server and your test checking the database.

The simplest way to resolve this is to wait before checking:

```
expect { click_button "Create"; sleep 2 }.to change(Answer, :count).by(count)
```

I don't like this. A better way to test this would be to check from the end user's perspective.

For example, after clicking 'Create', does the user see the answer on the answers page?

```
fill_in :title, :with => "My answer"

click_button 'Create'

page.should have_text "My answer"
```

Comment: I tried the sleep and it works, thanks for that! To the second option: is this special for this case b/c you don't want sleep's in your tests or is this a recommended pratice for all "request" specs?

Comment: Recommended practice for request tests. You want to do heavily mocked, tightly focused tests everywhere else but for request specs they should test the system as a whole with as little internal knowledge as possible.